# Magento - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method?

Tags: magento-1.7, validation, javascript, prototype-js

I am trying to implement a simple autocomplete form for custom pricing in Magento frontend.

I am using

```
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Along with `jQuery v1.10.2` which is being loaded before the other `JS` libraries.

```
        <action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/html5shiv.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
        <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>
      **<action method="addJs"><script>lib/validate.js</script></action>**
```

I've add my jquery code to the `catalog/product/view.phtml` file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        var validOptions = [];
        validOptions.push("FREE");
        var x = 1;
        while (x<1000) {
            if (x<100) {
                validOptions.push(""+x+"p");
            } else {
                var y = x.toString();
                var z = y.split('');
                validOptions.push("£"+z[0]+"."+z[1]+""+z[2]+"");
            }
            x++;
        }
        previousValue = "";

        jQuery('#ac').autocomplete({
            autoFocus: true,
            source: validOptions
        }).keyup(function() {
            var isValid = false;
            for (i in validOptions) {
                if (validOptions[i].toLowerCase().match(this.value.toLowerCase())) {
                    isValid = true;
                }
            }
            if (!isValid) {
                this.value = previousValue
            } else {
                previousValue = this.value;
            }
    });
    });

</script>
```

and for the input field I am using

```
<input id="ac" />
```

The problem is I am getting an error and for some reason the autocomplete won't work as required.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'
```

You can see a demo of the autocompletion [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fLv7d/)

Can anyone see what is wrong withmy setup?

Answer (score 1):

Try to define your jquery module after jQuery definition but before prototype.
Because after prototype definition `$` is not more jquery object and module cannot be initialized.

```
....
<action method="addJs"><script>lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>lib/validate.js</script></action>
<action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
....
```

**Update**

run

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

between jquery definition and validate module.

Comment: I still get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'`

Comment: Answer updated. Please take a look.

Comment: I had already added 
   `jQuery.noConflict();` to the code but I still get the error, see code above

Comment: You did not get me, that should be run just after jquery definition. And not inside template.

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevski For the purpose of what I am doing I also needed to include jQuery-UI into my page,,,

Comment: So does your problem still exist? And what is your question about jQuery-UI?

Comment: yes, the problem has now taken on a different form. This issue was resolved by adding jQuery-ui.js I now get a different error... see edit! `Uncaught TypeError: Object function each(iterator, context) {
    var index = 0;
    try {
      this._each(function(value) {
        iterator.call(context, value, index++);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      if (e != $break) throw e;
    }
    return this;
  } has no method 'toLowerCase' `

Comment: On which line of your code does this error happens?